# Django allow upload only specified files extensions

Tags: python, django

I want to allow django file modol only allow user for upload only specified extensions (mp4, mpg, etc....)

How can I do it ?

**Model.py:**

```
class Video(models.Model):    
    my_video = models.FileField(upload_to='uploaded_video/')
    title = models.CharField(max_length=180)
    date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
```

**view.py**

```
def upload(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        get_file = request.FILES['up_video']
        orginal_file_name = get_file.name   
        fs = FileSystemStorage()
        fs.save(orginal_file_name, get_file)
        form = VideoForm(request.POST, request.FILES)
        form.save()
```

Comment: Share also your `VideoForm`.

Answer (score 1):

```
    if request.method == 'POST':
        f = request.FILES['file']
        if f.name=='':
            return '<h2>Select a mp4 file to check</h2>'
        elif f.name.split(".")[1]=='mp4':
            # some code
```